# A who am I riddle

Tags: riddle

Who am I?

> Outcast, always alone at the end of the games we play
>   Beauty, defies me and leads to my demise
>   Jagged, the structure in which I stay
>   Fire, surrounds me its warmth I use as a disguise
>   Restless, even in death I return
>   Expendable, are the pawns I send forward to stop you

Hints will follow if you can't already guess who I am...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

> Bowser, of Super Mario Brothers fame

Outcast, always alone at the end of the games we play

> At the end of the game, Mario has to defeat Bowser

Beauty, defies me and leads to my demise

> Bowser steals the princess, and Mario wants to get her back, which is what brings around Bowser's demise

Jagged, the structure in which I stay

> He stays in a castle

Fire, surrounds me its warmth I use as a disguise

> There is fire on some levels

Restless, even in death I return

> After you beat Bowser, he comes back again in the next game

Expendable, are the pawns I send forward to stop you

> You know, the little guys you have to jump on, or POW off of a brick ledge?  Those guys.

How did I guess this?

> The rot13 of the acrostic of course.

Comment: Foiled so soon, before I could even give any hints!  Well yes you are correct 'The Handsome One'

Comment: The jagged structure I was referencing was his Shell just FYI

Comment: The jagged shell!  Makes more sense!

Answer (score 6):

Are you a

> King in Chess?

Outcast, always alone at the end of the games we play

> The King tends to be alone in the endgames.

Beauty, defies me and leads to my demise

> A beautifully played game of chess leads to the demise of the opposing king.

Jagged, the structure in which I stay

> Chess boards are jagged squares.

Fire, surrounds me its warmth I use as a disguise

> This I’m not sure.

Restless, even in death I return

> In a new game.

Expendable, are the pawns I send forward to stop you

> Yes, they are, (although not really depending on how you play).

Comment: I am not, I think that would have been a bit too straight forward :)

Answer (score 3):

You are ...

> The queen in a game of chess

Outcast, always alone at the end of the games we play

> The queen usually is either sacrificed or one of the last pieces in play

Beauty, defies me and leads to my demise

> The queen is very powerful and can sometimes lead novice players into making mistakes when they try to rely too heavily on her

Jagged, the structure in which I stay

> Pieces in chess can only move in rigid, predefined patterns

Fire, surrounds me its warmth I use as a disguise

> Not quite sure but maybe it is talking about other pieces surrounding the queen at the start of a game of chess?

Restless, even in death I return

> Most people choose to revive their queen if they make it to the other side with a pawn

Expendable, are the pawns I send forward to stop you

> The pawns in a game of chess are expendable

Comment: I am not.  I liked your justification for line 3 though +1 (wrong but a clever interpretation)

Answer (score 2):

Probably not correct but I think a fun answer.

You are

> Lord Sauron

Explanation

Outcast, always alone at the end of the games we play

> Sauron tries to attack the Free Peoples of Middle Earth multiple times and each time he is defeated and banished (outcast) for a time.

Beauty, defies me and leads to my demise

> He is defeated by elves, described to be a beautiful race. You could also say he is destroyed by the beauty of Frodo and Sam's freindship which allows them to persevere until the Ring is destroyed.

Jagged, the structure in which I stay

> Sauron resides in Dol Guldur and then later in Barad-dûr, both jagged structures.

Fire, surrounds me its warmth I use as a disguise

> Sauron projects a flaming lidless eye above his tower. Many think the eye is Sauron himself but the books never actually say that it is.

Restless, even in death I return

> Sauron has been defeated multiple times. Each time his spirit is banished for a while but returns after gaining strength. At least until the Ring is destroyed.

Expendable, are the pawns I send forward to stop you

> Sauron's main forces are orcs which come in large hordes and are very expendable.

Comment: Oh man I wish I could give you a +10, 'he is destroyed by the beauty of Frodo and Sam's freindship', that really made me laugh.  Unfortunately this is not the person I was thinking of.